# Convert odds ratio back to logit - logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I'm attempting to convert odd's ratios reported in results back to their original logit form. From what I've gathered,  the appropriate formula to do so is:

```
ln(OR) = Logit
ln(OR C.I) = Logit (C.I)
```

Is this correct or am I mistaken?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a course or read a book on logistic regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is the probability of an event, $o$ the odds (the ratio of probabilities of the event happening and it not happening), and $\alpha$ the log-odds, then

- $\alpha = \log_e\left(o\right) = \log_e\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$
- $o = e^\alpha = \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$
- $p = \frac{o}{1+o} = \frac{e^\alpha}{1+e^\alpha}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\alpha}}$

with the function $\log_e\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$ being called *the logit function* and $\frac{1}{1+e^{-\alpha}}$ being called *the logistic function*.  You can generalise the logistic function by adjusting the scale and location to have *a logistic function* which can be the results of logistic regression.

So what you suggest is essentially correct: you use logarithms to move between the odds and the log-odds.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a logistic regression coefficient into an odds ratio, you exponentiate it:

```
exp(.3196606)
# 1.37666
```

To convert it back, you log it:

```
log(1.37666)
# 0.3196606
```